# div по размеру background-image

Tags: html, css

Добрый вечер. div имеет ширину 100% и бэкграунд картинку, нужно сделать так, чтобы высота элемента была динамической с сохранением пропорций бэкграунда. Есть идеи?

Comment: Есть идеи. Не делать картинку фоном

Comment: Есть альтернатива?

Comment: Нет. Фоновая картинка по определению не может никак влиять на размеры блока. Вам нужен какой-то элемент который содержит «знание» о пропорциях картинки. Это не обязательно сама эта картинка, может быть что-нибудь другое, но фоновая картинка совершенно точно не подходит для этого.

Comment: А галочку не пора поставить?

Answer (score 4):

Вместо высоты используй `padding-top`:

```css
div {
  background: url(//placehold.it/350x150);
  background-size: cover;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-top: 42.857%; /* 150/350 */
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
background-size: [ <значение> | <проценты> | auto ]{1,2} | cover | contain
```

И дальше настраивайте, как нужно.
Подробнее, в том числе про поддержку в старых браузерах - http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-size

Comment: Чем это должно помочь?

Comment: Вопрос звучал так: "Есть идеи"?
Я дал идею. По вопросу сложно определить остальные требуемые параметры.

Ваш ответ также использует background-size, он более развернут, однако будет работать только в случае, когда все картинки одинаковых пропорций.